# Re-Render the directive for directive attribute value change in controller

Tags: angularjs, directive

There is a directive which represents an text input with some additional features within an angular controller. A maximum length is passed to the directive so the entering input text can be limited within the directive based on that parsing value. **The maximum Length will be determined using a controller variable which will be change time to time based on the user activities.** The directive is given below

```
<text-box-directive data-max-length="{{maxLength}}"></<text-box-directive>
```

This is the directive

```
angular.module('common.directives')
    .directive('textBoxDirective', function ($parse) {

    return {
        scope: {
            // some additional scope variables
        },

        link: function (scope.element, attrs) {
            scope.maxLength = $parse(attrs.maxLength)();
       }
    }
}
```

Since the **maxLength** variable is used as an attribute, even though the variable changes, the directive value will not be updated in the directive. I want this value to be updated when the controller value changes, but still the **maxLength**  variable is required to be an attribute to the directive

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here.  Angular uses dynamic re-rendering;  it **already** re-renders everything during a `$digest` cycle.  If you have something that should be affected by `$digest` that isn't, you should **show the code**.  Without a [mcve], the only thing others can offer is a blind guess.

Comment: Updated the question :)

Comment: why are you using `$parse` here? and why are you only using single braces (`{ }`) in your HTML?  just pass the property, and use normal two way binding in `scope`.....

Comment: @Claies, as he already mentioned, he wants it to be used as attribute rather than exposing it as two-way bound parameter.

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim but that explanation doesn't make sense.  where did this idea that an attribute can't be bound to scope come from? perhaps I overstated things when I say two way bound, one way bound would work as well....

Comment: I agree @Claies. The explanation is bit shady!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use `$parse` in your code. You should be receiving an interpolated value.

Now, let's say you have a variable `maxLength` in your controller `$scope` and you want to pass it to your directive. With that in mind, you used the directive as below in your template-

```
<text-box-directive max-text-length="{{maxLength}}"></<text-box-directive>
```

Now inside the directive link function, you get the attribute value using following code-

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  attrs.$observe('maxTextLength', function (newValue) {
    scope.maxLength = newValue;
  });
}
```

This way you also get notified whenever the value gets changed in controller `$scope`.

Comment: for further readings https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#attributes